# Mongodb parse string to Decimal/float

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

i'm new to mongoDB. I got my data as a string but i want to parse it to a `decimal/ float`. 
I found made this code but it doesn't seem to work. This is my code, it replaces - for 00, * for "", and parses it a float. It gives no errors, but the `parseFloat(doc).toFixed(2)`.

```
db.behuizingen.find().forEach(function(doc)
{
    var price = doc.Prijs.replace('€', ''); // it may be vary for your other document
    price = price.replace('-', '00');  
    price = price.replace('*', '');  
    doc.Prijs = Number(price);
    parseFloat(doc).toFixed(2)

    db.behuizingen.update({_id : doc._id} , doc;
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did this wrong. Convert first and the `Number()` function of the shell has nothing to do with it. So replacing that line an continuing:

```
doc.Prijs = parseFloat(parseFloat(price).toFixed(2));
db.moederborden.update({_id : doc._id} , doc );
```

But also be beware. That usage of `.update()` where the second argument is there will "replace" the entire document with the contents of `doc`.

You may want to do this instead:

```
doc.Prijs = parseFloat(parseFloat(price).toFixed(2));
var update = { "$set": {} };

Object.keys(doc).each(function(key) {
    update["$set"][key] = doc[key];
});

db.moederborden.update({_id : doc._id} , update );
```

Which uses the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator, so that any existing values that were not referenced in your `doc` object are not overwritten when writing to the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now it changes the `,`into a `.`. The type still says it is a string. How do I fix this?

Comment: @henktenk Sorry, I typed that wrong didn't I. It was meant to be wrapped twice. `parseFloat()` emits numeric from string, `.toFixed()` emits a string. So wrap all of that in `parseFloat()` again as shown.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where we had not had decimal serialisation enabled correctly and so I wanted to update documents that were already in our database to use the `Decimal` type instead of `String`. I used the following script:

```
db.MyCollection.find({ Price: { $type: "string" } }).forEach(function(doc) { 
    print('Updating price for ' + doc._id);
    db.MyCollection.update( 
       { _id: doc._id },
       { $set : { Price: NumberDecimal(doc.Price) } }
    )
})
```

This only retrieves the documents that need updating by filtering on the field type, and then uses `NumberDecimal` to convert the string into a decimal.

Comment: NumberDecimal was introduced in MongoDB v4.0. I am using v3.2 and using parseFloat and parseInt seems to be the only way to change the data type of a field.

Comment: @Sheng I think it was actually introduced in v3.4 (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/#numeric-decimal), so still later than your version but earlier than v4.0